# Working on a freelance project, isolated by co-workers, how to hold good relations with the customer?

Tags: freelancing

Since some months I am part of a freelance project, doing mainly by people working on in their after-work free time.

I was mainly absolutely incapable to actually work in it, on the following reasons:

1. I was inserted into the project after it was already nearly dead. I was inserted into it with the goal to re-vitalize. I couldn't do this.
2. People already working on that has seemed me with nearly-open hostility. Their main reason was that they've seen my insertion into the project as the sign of the unsatisfiedness of the customer with their work.
3. They've used intensively their very special technologies tuned to their skills. It had probably the reason to make themselfes unavoidable in the project.
4. There were also tasks I could have done effectively, more effective as they. It was because they didn't require the skills only they have, instead they belong to my knowledge area. They made these tasks very fast, on the spot, after my insertion, instead of me. Before that, these tasks were in the "somehow never done, but always promised" state. I think, their goal was to isolate me. In their version, they made them because "I was slow".

I've seen that in some weeks after I was inserted into the project, and I think, the professional reaction had been that I explain these openly to the customer and try to peacefully leave.

I've explained (1)-(4) to him. In his view, he see this as my "incapability and unwillingness to work and to adapt to my co-workers". Before this project, I had a quite good relation with the customer, now it is very bad. Despite his communication, I think he also understands my arguments, but somehow he ignores them.

My goal would be to optimize the chances of a possible next project in the future.

I further think that the best would be to leave, but I would still remain if it is better.

Which is the better? To leave, or to remain? If I would leave, how to do this with the possible minimal disaster to our work relations?

Note: I actually don't want the money I could have got for my work until now. My only goal would be to hold the possible best relations with him.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I would want to work with this team in the future only if I don't have a better option. They were *really* very hostile and undermined my reputation before the customer. I want to work with the customer (in different teams), but ideally not with them: although the relation became much better with the team, it required *a lot* of tolerance from me. And I am simply not accustomed to a team where they are friendly only if I don't work. And they still try to avoid me doing any useful in *their project*.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I want to hold the possible best relations, because I don't like the dishonored discharges, and I think it maximizes my chances to a next project from him. Well, it is not really easy to understand your arguments, but exactly this makes them very worthy. I've thought if I explain the truth - I am isolated by the already existing team - it sounds reasonable for the customer. But it seems it doesn't, why?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, this is my goal. Thank you very much! If you convert it to an answer, I would be happy to upvote/accept it. I changed the title, maybe it sounds more clear now.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ok. And now?

Comment: No matter how sour your relationships with your coworkers has turned, badmouthing them before the customer is most certainly not professional behaviour.

Comment: @MaskedMan It is not badmouthing, it is the truth. I can remain silent to not badmouth them only because it wouldn't look professional.

Comment: This is just odd.   Are you hired by and paid by the customer directly?

Comment: @Paparazzi No, there is an intermediary contract company in the picture. Actually I had good relation with them, the end-customer I didn't know until now.

Comment: Not clear who "him" is.   Your communication is not clear.   Your recognition of team dynamics seems lacking.    Don't take internal problems to the customer unless you answer directly to the customer and hired by the customer.  Even this try and resolve internally first.

Comment: @Morning Star It doesn't matter whether it is the "truth" or not. The customer will see it as badmouthing when you publicly criticize your coworkers, regardless of who is "right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not working professionally, you are focusing on the people, not the work, you've dug yourself a hole, and you're not going to live it down. In future you analyse the work from all angles before you take on a job. You make sure you can do it, that you have the support and authority to get it done and that jealous colleagues cannot affect you. Most importantly, you should have a clear strategy to accomplish your goal which you can follow. When you do it this way, it doesn't matter so much if people try and sabotage you. Quite often they just make themselves look like the problem.

I think it's too late, you have antagonised people who wanted to dislike you, you have upset the customer, you have not remained positive. All without a strategy to successfully complete a 'nearly dead' project.

I don't see any positive outcome in this unless you stop blaming others (even if they're wrong) and work on a plan that will actually have a good outcome for the client. But it's going to be an uphill battle, because you should have done this at the start.

Comment: I have good contact with my co-workers... it was hard, but now I have.

Comment: Good luck to you

Comment: I am really sorry for that, until that I thought I weren't so bad... but it seems, I am.

Comment: No, you're just learning, same as all of us.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will take the uphill battle, and I will try to accept the consequences of my mistakes. It will likely mean a dishonored discharge of the customer.

Comment: Yeah, I'd always take the battle rather than give up, best of luck